# GetHashCode when one of properties can be null

Tags: c#, .net, hashcode, .net-4.8, gethashcode

I am currently trying to figure out how to deal with situation,
where I want to use some object as a key in dictionary, therefore I need it
to have overriden `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods. The problem is that one of the properties of my object is nullable.

```
public class Car
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public CarBodyType Type { get; set; }

   public int? LifeSpanInYears { get; set; }


   public override bool Equals(object o)
   {
      // ...
   }

   public override int GetHashCode()
   {
      var result = base.GetHashCode();
      result = (result * 397) ^ this.Id.GetHashCode();
      result = (result * 397) ^ this.Type.GetHashCode();

      // Here ... What is the best approach? Currently, result will be 1 if LifeSpanInYears is null.
      result = (result * 397) ^ (this.LifeSpanInYears?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);

      return result;
   }
}
```

What is the best approach when dealing with possible null value of one of the properties?
My opinion is that this would be the best approach.

```
if (this.LifeSpanInYears.HasValue)
{
   result = (result * 397) ^ this.LifeSpanInYears.GetHashCode();
}
```

At least I will get rid of the problem, where result of GetHashCode is 1 everytime any of the nullable properties is null.

What's your take on this?

Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: FYI: Keep in mind that using mutable objects as dictionary key can be problematic. Especially such objects that are mutable from the outside, like for example through public property setters. Mutating them while they are being keys in a dictionary can and will mess with dictionary lookups.

Comment: Note that `int?` is just C# syntactic sugar for the `Nullable<int>` type, which overrides [GetHashCode()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.gethashcode). So, you could just simply do `result = (result * 397) ^ this.LifeSpanInYears.GetHashCode();` without any explicit checks for LifeSpanInYears having a value or not. Or do you have a particular reason for avoiding the Nullable<T>.GetHashCode method?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace No, there is no particular reason for it. Seems like I just didn't  think it through enough. I got confused because of this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/implement-value-objects
public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return GetEqualityComponents()
            .Select(x => x != null ? x.GetHashCode() : 0)
            .Aggregate((x, y) => x ^ y);
    }

The suggested approach there is to use 0 instead of null.GetHashCode().

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Ok, so it's fine to use just (Nullable<int>).GetHashCode(), I get that now. But may I ask how that method behaves, when the value is null? Just out of curiosity...

Comment: With regard to the example you mentioned, note that it acts on an `object`-typed variable, not on a nullable value type like you do here. And "_how that method behaves, when the value is null_", that's precisely why linked to the documentation of that method in my previous comment. So you can easily look it up... ;-)

Comment: Sorry for being lazy ;) Seems like your response is sufficient. I will read the provided article. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Just one follow up question. Do you by any change have an opinion as to why the community is using the member?.GetHashCode() ?? 0 approach? Seems like it's widely spread... That's why I got confused, I was thinking that the community is wiser than me, so I should just copy paste xD Good example is that ValueObject implementation in microsoft docs...

Comment: You have to differentiate between nullable value types and reference types. Nullable value types are actually the type Nullable<T>, which itself is a value type. A nullable value type variable being null is technically not the same as a reference type variable being null. As a value type cannot be really null (not even Nullable<T>; treating a Nullable<T> value like it is being null is just the C# compiler being cheeky), it is safe to invoke Nullable<T>.GetHashCode() at any time on any possible Nullable<T> value.

Comment: On the other hand, for reference types a null value is an actual real null value, and you can't invoke GetHashCode() on an actual real null value (you can try, but you will get a NullReferenceException). Hence why null checks are necessary for invoking GetHashCode() on reference types but not when invoking GetHashCode() on nullable value types.

Comment: Ok, now I really get it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using the built-in [`HashCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode) struct:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    HashCode hashCode = new();
    hashCode.Add(this.Id);
    hashCode.Add(this.Type);
    hashCode.Add(this.LifeSpanInYears);
    return hashCode.ToHashCode();
}
```

...or:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return HashCode.Combine(this.Id, this.Type, this.LifeSpanInYears);
}
```

It takes care of the nullable values. You don't have to do anything special for them.

I would expect it to be slower than your multiply+XOR approach, but it should produce a better quality hashcode. The source code of the `HashCode` struct is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/HashCode.cs).

**Note:** the `HashCode` type is available from .NET Core 2.1 and later.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunatelly, my question is regarding the .NET framework 4.8, so it seems like i can't use the HashCode struct.

Comment: @BrunoPfohl yep, the `HashCode` is available from .NET Core 2.1 and later. I added the `.net-4.8` tag in the question.